# How to fix NEXTVAL returning null in insert query but returns correct value when executed alone in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-sequence

When I execute the following insert query:

```
insert into FEED_STAGING_GOOD_TRADE (JOBEXECUTIONID, STAGINGID, ROWNUMBER, system, traderef, mtmvaluation, mtmvaluationccy, prcmtmquality, prcdate) 
values (64, NEXTVAL('FEED_STAGING_TRADE_SEQ') ,2,'RMS','TRD3',1.11111111E8,'USD',100.0,'2011-12-09 +00'::timestamp)
```

I get the following output:

```
ERROR: null value in column "tradestagingid" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (46, 64, null, 2, null, null, null, RMS, null, null, TRD3, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 111111111, USD, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 100, 2011-12-09 00:00:00, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).
```

The third column which is supposed to be filled by the `NEXTVAL` function result is being sent null, which is violating a certain non-nullity constraint.

However when I execute `NEXTVAL` independently like this:

```
select NEXTVAL('FEED_STAGING_TRADE_SEQ');
```

The function returns a correct value as shown below in the screenshot:

[image: nextval]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your insert provides a value for the column `stagingid`, but not for the column `tradestagingid` (to which the error message refers)

You INSERT statement doesn't even list a column named `tradestagingid` so the default value for that column will be used.

As you seem to expect the `tradestagingid` to be populated with the sequence value, you need to change the column list of your INSERT and use `tradestagingid` instead of `stagingid`. Or better: define it as an identity column, so it gets populated automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer it's actually pretty insightful, the confusion for me arose when I populated a data from a database into another empty one, they both presumably have the same exact structure since the empty database's structure has been initialized by a certain script, turns out one of them had stagingid as primary key for the FEED_STAGING_GOOD_TRADE table and the other one had tradestagingid.